# How jungle test net show account history?

Tags: transactions, apiendpoint

I am getting a history of account on jungle test net. Like this:
`cleos --url http://junglehistory.cryptolions.io get actions <my account>  -1 -2 -j` 
The problem is it shows the actions till 14 Feb 2019. But transaction which is done in the last 10-20 minute is not reflected here.

But I check the history of the same account on jungle test net, There it showing all transaction in history.
what API endpoint is jungle2 test are using?

Comment: Have you tried without/with different the offsets? Pretty sure Cleos expects positive values for offsets except '-1' which is the only special case.

Comment: Yes I tried, This is also correct. I think something is not good with jungle test net database.

Comment: I find that same transaction_id is inserted twice with different mongo_id.